# how to select input field under asp:repeater element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="radpnl1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_Template" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table id="tblusers" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%" class="table_row2">
                        Name :
                    </td>
                    <td class="table_row2">
                        <input type="text" id="txt_template" name="txt_template" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TemplateName") %>'
                            maxlength="200" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="hdnDeletedIds" name="hdnDeletedIds" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
      </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am new to `Jquery`. I want to know if i can select all the input fields above with `id="txt_template"` to compare their name using a `Jquery` function. As this is is under `<asp:repeater>` control, I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Yes you can. Do you want to compare then on button click?

Comment: yes. can i just call a javascript function. but i'm new to this and need help

Comment: You want to call a JavaScript function on Button click to compare all the elements?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the repeater, You need to use class instead of id. I'm not really sure but I thing the id you give to a server control with runat=server is not essentially the rendered id.

So use a class as follows

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="radpnl1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_Template" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table id="tblusers" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" class="table_row2">
                    Name :
                </td>
                <td class="table_row2">
                    <input type="text" class='aSuperInput' id="txt_template" name="txt_template" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TemplateName") %>'
                        maxlength="200" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdnDeletedIds" name="hdnDeletedIds" value="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
  </table>
</ContentTemplate>
```

JQuery

```
  $('.aSuperInput').change(function(){
     //----
  });
```

or

```
  $('.aSuperInput').select(function(){
     //----.blur(), .focus(), .unblur(), ect.
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. will it be easier just to use javascript then. is it possible to just use javascript and compare the name for each element.